# How to add horizontal separator in a dynamically created ContextMenu?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpfdatagrid

I was looking for the solution on the internet but was not able to find it within my sample. I need to add a separator between Context menu item that are generated from code behind. I tried to add it with such code lines like below but without success.

```
this.Commands.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
```

I am wondering if someone can help. Thank you in advance.

Context Menu XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding}" />
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}" />
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Parameter}" />
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

C# that added in the method:

```
this.Commands = new ObservableCollection<ICommand>();
        this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole1);
        this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole2);
        this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole3);
        this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole4);
        //this.Add(new ToolStripSeparator()); 
        this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole5);
        this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole6);
        this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole7);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT:**

My first answer to this question, though it actually worked, does not follow the MVVM design principle. I am now providing an MVVM approach and leaving the original answer below for reference.

You can create a behavior to solve this problem.

XAML:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_File" menu:MenuBehavior.MenuItems="{Binding Path=MenuItemViewModels, Mode=OneWay}">

    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModelBase> MenuItemViewModels => new List<MenuItemViewModelBase>
{
    new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Hello" },
    new MenuItemSeparatorViewModel(),
    new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "World" }
};
```

Behavior:

```
public class MenuBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MenuItems",
            typeof(IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModelBase>), typeof(MenuBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(MenuItemsChanged));

    public static IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModelBase> GetMenuItems(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw (new ArgumentNullException("element"));
        }
        return (IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModelBase>)element.GetValue(MenuItemsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMenuItems(DependencyObject element, IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModelBase> value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw (new ArgumentNullException("element"));
        }
        element.SetValue(MenuItemsProperty, value);
    }

    private static void MenuItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menu = (MenuItem)d;

        if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
        {
            menu.ItemsSource = ConvertViewModelsToFrameworkElements((IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModelBase>)e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> ConvertViewModelsToFrameworkElements(IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModelBase> viewModels)
    {
        var frameworkElementList = new List<FrameworkElement>();

        foreach (var viewModel in viewModels)
        {
            switch (viewModel)
            {
                case MenuItemViewModel mi:
                    frameworkElementList.Add(new MenuItem
                    {
                        Header = mi.Header,
                        Command = mi.Command,
                        Icon = mi.Icon
                    });
                    break;

                case MenuItemSeparatorViewModel s:
                    frameworkElementList.Add(new Separator());
                    break;
            }
        }
        return frameworkElementList;
    }
}
```

Classes:

```
public class MenuItemViewModelBase
{
}

public class MenuItemViewModel : MenuItemViewModelBase
{
    public object Header { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public object Icon { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItemSeparatorViewModel : MenuItemViewModelBase
{
}
```

**Original Answer:**

Or, instead of having your ContextMenu bind to a collection of commands, bind it to a collection of FrameworkElements then you can add either MenuItems or Separators directly to the collection and let the Menu control do all the templating....

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

C#:

```
this.Commands = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();

this.Commands.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Menuitem 2", Command = MainWindow.AddRole1});
this.Commands.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Menuitem 2", Command = MainWindow.AddRole2});
this.Commands.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Menuitem 3", Command = MainWindow.AddRole3});
this.Commands.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Menuitem 4", Command = MainWindow.AddRole4});

this.Commands.Add(new Separator);

this.Commands.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Menuitem 5", Command = MainWindow.AddRole5});
this.Commands.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Menuitem 6", Command = MainWindow.AddRole6});
this.Commands.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Menuitem 7", Command = MainWindow.AddRole7});
```

Just used this approach in my app - the separator looks better this way also.

Comment: Not such a great idea if you want to maintain a model-view-separation though.

Comment: Not sure why. This code is located in the ViewModel so is separate from the View. True is contains View-related UI controls and if you wanted to keep those out of the ViewModel you could put all the functionality into a behavior and have that bind to a list of commands for the menu items with a dummy command for the separator.

Comment: Downvoted because you shouldn't put MenuItems in a ViewModel. It's a ViewModel, not a view.

Answer (score 52):

I did this once and used a `null` as my separator. From the XAML, I then styled the template to use a separator if the datacontext was null

Code behind:

```
this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole4);
this.Add(null); 
this.Commands.Add(MainWindow.AddRole5);
```

XAML was something like this:

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding}" />
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Parameter}" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Hope I got the syntax right - I don't have an IDE on this machine to verify the code

**EDIT**

Here is an example template for the context menu separator. I am putting it in `ContextMenu.Resources`, although you could put this anywhere you want in your application as long as the ContextMenu can access it.

```
<ContextMenu.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuSeparatorTemplate">
        <Separator />
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContextMenu.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. However, it does not work yet. I cannot insert separator yet. I changed value to be 'Value="{DynamicResource MenuSeparatorTemplate}"' and was able to debug the solution. The result is that separator is not visible and that area has rollover state over empty menuitem. I am wondering if it is possible to fix.

Comment: You need to create the `MenuSeparatorTemplate`. Since it isn't created, nothing is being shown.

Comment: How to access generic Separator template from datatrigger?

Comment: I added ControlTemplate and named it 'MenuSeparatorTemplate'. However, the solution is crashing when I am trying to open context menu. I believe it is very close and great solution. I just have some syntax problem. Ideally, I'd like to be able to access generic separator style that used througout the project.

Comment: @vladc77: I added an example ControlTemplate to the answer. I've tested the code and it works fine without any crashes.

Comment: Grear. It works. However, the style is different from hormal generic separator style. There is no kind of 3D effect. Do you have any ideas why it can be missed? Thank you again.

Comment: I just draw separator there without adding <Separator /> code line. It works great now. I am just wondering why its style missed.

Comment: Yes, the separator looks weird - it goes across the entire menu (it should not cover the icon area on the left) and it is much thicker than a normal separator. Other than this, the solution looks promising.

Answer (score 12):

I have modified the solution provided by Rachel above to correct the Separator style.  I realize this post is old, but still one of the top results on Google.  In my situation, I was using it for a Menu vs a ContextMenu, but the same should work.

**XAML**

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuSeparatorTemplate">
            <Separator>
                <Separator.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
                </Separator.Style>
            </Separator>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding MenuItemHeader}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuItemCommand}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding MenuItemCommandParameter}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MenuItemCollection}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```

[Without Separator Style Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO2th.png)

[With Separator Style Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3OBT.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Seems this is _almost_ an answer, so I'd recommend removing the part about it being a comment, and add more context to make it a complete solution.

Comment: I used `{x:Null}` as a value to indicate separator.
However if user manage to click exactly on the separator program crashed.
Apparently it tried to invoke `Command` on the null value.
I created special static value instead of null: `{x:Static MyItem.MySpecialStatic} and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use ItemTemplateSelector:

```
public class MenuItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SeparatorTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var menuItem = container.GetVisualParent<MenuItem>();
        if (menuItem == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unknown MenuItem type");
        }

        if (menuItem.DataContext == null)
        {
            return SeparatorTemplate;
        }

        return menuItem.ItemTemplate;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewContentMenuItems}" >
                                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplateSelector>
                                    <templateSelectors:MenuItemTemplateSelector>
                                        <templateSelectors:MenuItemTemplateSelector.SeparatorTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Separator />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </templateSelectors:MenuItemTemplateSelector.SeparatorTemplate>
                                    </templateSelectors:MenuItemTemplateSelector>
                                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplateSelector>
                            </ContextMenu>
```

In model:

```
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ViewContentMenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            var temp = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
            temp.Add(null);
            temp.Add(CreateFolderMenuItem);
            return temp;
        }
    }
private MenuItem CreateFolderMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            var createFolderMenuItem = new MenuItem()
            {
                Header = "New Folder",
                Icon = new Image
                {
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/icons/folderWinCreate.png", UriKind.Relative)),
                    Height = 16,
                    Width = 16
                }
            };

            Message.SetAttach(createFolderMenuItem, "CreateDocumentsFolder");//Caliburn example
            return createFolderMenuItem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not put View elements in a View Model, much less a model.

Answer (score 0):

WPF provides exactly what you're looking for - it's called "Separator":

```
this.Commands.Add(new Separator());
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this correctly for **MVVM** you have to define your own item interface (f.e. *IMenuItem*), create derived classes for ***Menu*** / ***ContextMenu*** and for ***MenuItem***, in these classes override following virtual protected methods :

```
ItemsControl.PrepareContainerForItemOverride
ItemsControl.ClearContainerForItemOverride
ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride
ItemsControl.IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride
```

Ensure that this methods create for items of type *IMenuItem* containers of your new derived from ***MenuItem*** type with binding all needed properties, here you can differentiate different types of *IMenuItem* to show normal items, separator or some thins else. For unknown types call base implementation.

Now, if you will bind *ItemsSource* property of your new derived from ***Menu***/***ContextMenu*** control with collection of *IMenuItem*, it will show you expected result without need to now View-stuff on ViewModel side.