# ContextMenu in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, contextmenu

I want to bind a contextmenu to a list of commands.

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ItemContextCommands, Converter={StaticResource commandToStringConverter}}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate DataType="MenuItem">
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

The `commandToStringConverter` simply converts a list of commands to a list of strings calling the `ToString()` on each command in the list.

How can I achieve that the `Command` in each `MenuItem` is called?

Comment: You *probabbly* should think about using another yet converter that converts every single {Binding} to actual command call.

Comment: the converter returns the a List of Func?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would use a small "view model" to hold the informations for such a command.

```
class ContextAction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name;
    public ICommand Action;
    public Brush Icon;
}
```

make a collection inside your view model which should get the context actions like

```
ObservableCollection<ContextAction> Actions {get;set;}
```

and simply bind this collection to your `ContextMenu`.

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" />
```

The `ItemTemplate` for the contextmenu items can now access the name, the command and whatever else you might need. It might be useful to change the `CommandParameter` as well so that it will call the command with the actions owning element, not with the action itself.

Comment: Anyone have an idea how to handle a ContextMenu with separators and submenus?  This solution appears to be only useful for a homogenous set of objects.

Comment: Submenues are just as easy. You just give the ContextMenu an ItemContainerStyle with a setter for ItemsSource and bind to a new property of type ObservableCollection<ContextAction> inside a ContextAction. For Separators see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823760/how-to-add-horizontal-separator-in-a-dynamically-created-contextmenu) solution.

Answer (score 15):

i use something like this:

```
public class ContextMenuVM
{ 
    public string Displayname {get;set;}
    public ICommand MyContextMenuCommand {get;set;}
}
```

in your contextmenu datacontext:

```
public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuVM> MyCommandList {get;set;}
```

in your xaml

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MyCommandList}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate DataType="MenuItem">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Displayname}" Command="{Binding MyContextMenuCommand}"></MenuItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    </ContextMenu>
```

its written without ide, so maybe some syntax errors in there

Comment: This solution has nested control of MenuItem

Answer (score 7):

An improved XAML version of @blindmils solution below:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MyCommandList}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Displayname}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyContextMenuCommand }" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```