# WPF binding ContextMenu to ContextMenu Property in VM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

In a legacy view model there is a ContextMenu property

`

```
public static ContextMenu DropDownMenu
{
  get
  {
       return _DropDownMenu;
  }
}
```

`

I want to bind the DropDownMenu property to the View:

`

```
<DockPanel.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu x:Name="menu" 
               DataContext="{x:Static local:VM.DropDownMenu}" >
  </ContextMenu>
</DockPanel.ContextMenu>
```

`

Unfortunately, It doesn't work. Due to some reason, I'm not able to modify view model, can anyone please help me to correct the binding in the View?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<DockPanel  ContextMenu ="{Binding Source={x:Static local:VM.DropDownMenu}, Mode=OneWay}">
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also,

```
<DockPanel  ContextMenu ="{Binding DropDownMenu, Source={x:Static local:VM}}"/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this works, and what's wrong with the OP's original code?

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly consume Controls in your ViewModel.

There is a different solution at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567124/823369)