# Menu item that sets properties on menu open

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently trying to create a dynamically created context menu. I'm currently binding a `ObservableCollection<MenuItem>` to the `ItemsSource` property on the context menu. I now want to set the visibility of the items in the list when the menu opens depending on what I have selected.
I tried Inheriting from `MenuItem` like this

```
public class CtContextMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public delegate Visibility VisibilityDelegate();
    public VisibilityDelegate IsVisibleDelegate = null;
}
```

And I want to set `Visibility` to the result of the `VisibilityDelegate` when the context menu is opened but I can't find any event or method that is called on the `MenuItem` when the context menu is opened
Is there a way to do it or is it do I have to just create all the items of the menu inside a function listening to `ContextMenuOpening`?

Comment: *"listening to ContextMenuOpening"* - yes. Enumerate menu items and call that delegate either directly or via property (if data template binding is used). Consider to add a little of [mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15566824/1997232) instead of using custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<CtContextMenuItem>` where the `CtContextMenuItem` type has a `Visibility` or `bool` *property* that you can bind to in your XAML. Something like this:

```
public class CtContextMenuItem
{
    public Visibility IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding TheSourceCollection}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible}" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```