# How do I bind to a context MenuItem header in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I'm attempting to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567124/1094670) on how to make an MVVM context menu in WPF. It sounds easy enough: "The ItemTemplate for the contextmenu items can now access the name, the command and whatever else you might need."

There's no mention of changing data contexts, visual trees, etc.

**Here's my ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public class ContextAction : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public string HeaderText;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<ContextAction> ContextMenuActions { get; set; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    ContextMenuActions = new ObservableCollection<ContextAction>();
    ContextMenuActions.Add(new ContextAction { HeaderText = "Foo" });
    ContextMenuActions.Add(new ContextAction { HeaderText = "Bar" });
    ContextMenuActions.Add(new ContextAction { HeaderText = "Baz" });
  }
}
```

**...and my XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid Background="red">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuActions}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate DataType="MenuItem">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding HeaderText}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I can see that the items get added to the context menu. Right-clicking on the grid produces a menu with three blank items. However, the header bindings are not working (each menu item is blank). Did I miss something from the answer I linked? Do I need to make some sort of proxy class [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647539/1094670)? That seems rather convoluted for a simple task like making a context menu and isn't even hinted at in the first answer I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind to **properties**, not **fields**.

```
public string HeaderText {get; set;}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh man. I knew that. I feel so dumb. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was time for you to have a break :)